# "Entity not authorized" error on npx expo start

Tags: graphql

Whenever I run `npx expo start` I receive this error. I am expecting to run my app on expo Go.

Here is the error I receive:

```
[GraphQL] Entity not authorized: AccountEntity[8cd24a8a-bf0b-472d-977e-3a4369162406] (viewer = RegularUserViewerContext[c8c14ed4-5683-46ef-96fe-d030b8aeab22], action = READ, ruleIndex = -1).
```

Comment: There's not enough here to go on. It looks like your app is connecting to a GraphQL server on startup and that server is returning an auth error on the initial query.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try that appears to be resolving the issue is setting the project ID in `app.json`, like this:

```
"extra": {
     "eas": {
       "projectId": "xxxxxxxxx"
     }
   }
```

This can either be retrieved from your project on https://expo.dev 34 or it can be populated by running as init

Noted : If it an imported project remove the project ID